# Move Google Maps Center

Tags: google-maps

I need Google maps to load so the marker is off center or in other words, the center of the map is not in the center but moved to the right.  I hope this makes sense.

This is from the script I am using.

```
function setCenterCoords($lon,$lat) {
    $this->centerLatitude = (float) $lat;
    $this->centerLongitude = (float) $lon;
}
```

How would I make it so the center shows up on the right 2/3 of the page instead of in the middle of the page? Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Use the method [setCenter(latlng)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) to center the map as you need.

Comment: thank you.  I am new at this.  This is from the script I am using.

     function setCenterCoords($lon,$lat) {
        $this->centerLatitude = (float) $lat;
        $this->centerLongitude = (float) $lon;
    }

How would I make it so the center shows up on the right 2/3 of the page instead of in the middle?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As described in the Google Maps API documentation, assuming that you're using the JavaScript API, you can set the center in the map options:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#MapOptions

Comment: thank you. I am new at this. This is from the script I am using. function setCenterCoords($lon,$lat) { $this->centerLatitude = (float) $lat; $this->centerLongitude = (float) $lon; } How would I make it so the center shows up on the right 2/3 of the page instead of in the middle? Thank you